# Trying to create a document whenever a user signs up

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a document in firestore in the path "users" and the name user.uid every time a new user signs up. In this document I want to store some attributes such as firstname, lastname, email and uid. The issue i have is that the auth works perfectly, but no document is created.

```js
var email = signupEmail.value;
var password = signupPassword.value;
var firstname = signupFirstname.value;
var lastname = signupLastname.value;
var password_repeat = signupRepeatPw.value;
const auth = getAuth();
const db = getFirestore();

if (firstname != "" && lastname != "") {
    if (password == password_repeat) {
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then(async (userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
            await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
                firstName: firstname,
                lastName: lastname,
                accountLevel: 0,
                UID: user.uid,
                email: email,
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Document successfully written!");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
```

Any help will be very appreciated as I have been stuck on this for quite some time!

Best regards,
Isak

Comment: Does either the `then()` or `catch` of the `setDoc` call get called? Is there any (error) message showing in the JavaScript console during this call?

Comment: Hi! `then()` or `catch()` of the `setDoc` does not get called. There are no errors showing during this call.

Comment: That's unexpected. Did you verify that the `setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid)` actually gets called?

Comment: `setDoc` does not get called I dont think, as the database doesnt get updated even when I hard code for `user.uid`. I tried to console log above the line `await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid),`, and it does log, but still doesnt seem to run `setDoc` correctly.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think I found something new. When I try to use `addDoc` instead of `setDoc`, I get an error returned: `"Document references must have an even number of segments, but users/"userID"/iTVGZoIaCIaz3wvsG4Bh has 3."` I dont know why Firebase adds this last `/iTV....` part, as the userID contains none of this.

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment: of course addDoc wouldnt work in this case, as that only accepts one segment: `users`, as firestore would in this case generate its own ID. As I want every document to be the UID this solution would not work either way.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is struggling with this issue, I fixed my mistake.

The problem was that I redirected the user to their profile page when the auth state changed, from another script tag running simaltaniously. This led to the code redirecting the user before the promise was complete and therefore it does not update the db.

Best regards,
Isak

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).